# Constructing an approximation of the S&P 500 volatility smile with publicly available data

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, volatility-smile

Besides of the [VIX](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EVIX%20Historical%20Prices) there is another vol datum publicly available for the S&P 500: the [SKEW](http://www.cboe.com/micro/skew/introduction.aspx).

Do you know a procedure with which one can extrapolate other implied vols of the S&P 500 smile with these data (or with other publicly available [vol data](http://www.cboe.com/micro/IndexSites.aspx))?

**Addendum:**
I created a follow up question [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/how-to-calculate-the-most-realistic-option-prices-with-additional-publicly-avail).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to create? 30-day implied vol curve?

Comment: @onlyvix: Exactly!

Comment: You should be aware that the vix is *not* the volatility, it's the sqrt of the 30 par varswap rate - the two are not the same.

Comment: @will: What are you getting at? VIX stands for *V*olatility *I*nde*X* and it is built to measure expected *volatility*.

Comment: @vonjd It may have been, but read the [spec](https://www.cboe.com/micro/vix/vixwhite.pdf), google it a bit, you'll see that it's not the vol. it's the sqrt of the par 30 day varswap rate - the two are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @will: Yes, there are dozens of volatility measures out there because volatility as such cannot be observed directly - but again: What are you getting at? What is the relevance concerning my question?

Comment: I was just pointing out that the vix is not the volatility, and that it actually gives you no more information than if you had the option chain on each date (though you don't). The  availability of historical option data has probably changed a lot in the last few years though - is there anything on quantopian? does pandas have historical data? From what i remember of looking, most of these only give you live prices, building up a decent backtest is going to take a while. you can by 5 years of data for a single asset for $2.50 [here](https://www.historicaloptiondata.com/node/38).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known expansion of *implied volatility* in moments (I'll find the reference)

\begin{equation}
\textrm{IV} = \textrm{vol} * (1 + \frac{\textrm{skew}}{6} * \textrm{LMM} + \frac{\textrm{kurt}}{24}*(\textrm{LMM}^2-1))
\end{equation}

where *log-moneyness* is

\begin{equation}
\textrm{LMM} = \frac{\log{\frac{\textrm{strike}}{\textrm{forward}}}}{\textrm{vol} * \sqrt{T}}.
\end{equation}

Use VIX for vol.

If I remember correctly SKEW index is $100-100*\textrm{skew}$, so $\textrm{skew} = \frac{100-\textrm{SKEW}}{100}$.
Kurtosis is unknown, but you could try to use *VVIX* index and re-scale it in some way.

Or maybe another way would be to take the equation and regress for multipliers for VIX, VIX*SKEW, and VIX*VVIX using IV smile data.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer already, but could you please provide the reference? It would be super great if you could give an example calculation also :-) Another thing: Are kurtosis and VVIX equivalent? Thank you again!

Comment: @vonjd:  VVIX is more like the varvol (or vol of vol) parameter found in stochastic volatility models.  What onlyvix provides here is a common parameterization of the skew curve with convenient simplicity.  See [this question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/620/is-there-a-popular-curve-fitting-formula-of-options-skew-vs-strike-price-or-vs-d/622#622) for more on that.

Comment: Brian B is correct, VVIX is definitely not kurtosis, but probably can be used as a proxy if properly scaled. The reference is here http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/papers/bias.pdf, see page 8, formula (16)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, closing options prices can be [downloaded](ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle/stleqt) from the exchange, so the data necessary to get the skew is available.

If for some reason you don't want to use those closing prices, it *is* possible to obtain a vol skew from VIX and SKEW.  You would need to fit the parameters of a stochastic volatility model (such as [Heston's](http://www.math.umn.edu/~bemis/IMA/MMI2008/calibrating_heston.pdf)) to the VOL and SKEW data.  It's [hard to do carefully](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/skew-and-vix-relations) but easy to do approximately.   Then the S&P skew is whatever has been implied by that model.

(Edit:  if you are willing to include the VVIX, your fits will become much better.  The VVIX tels you the size of the volatility-of-volatility parameter in a stochastic vol model.)

Comment: Thank you Brian, where do you get these historic closing option prices?

Comment: Updated with link to prices.  It's not historic, but obviously you can download and form your own historic series.